# relative URLs in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26 and TinyMCE v3.38.
The .js file of the TinyMSC is stored under this directory:
http://www.mysite/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

In the page where the users can post new topic,
the URL of this page is like this:
http://www.mysite/user/newpost

Now I need to add the javascript to this page, and I have tried these:
echo $javascript->link('/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'); 
echo $javascript->link('js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'); 
echo $javascript->link('../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'); 
But the tiny_mce.js can not be reached.

Comment: What's the HTML source look like for the first `echo`? That should work.

Comment: They're all wrong. Cake already knows about the js folder and you don't need the extension.

It should be echo $javascript->link('tiny_mce/tiny_mce');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Cake already knows that your javascript is in /js/ through using the $javascript->link() structure in the first place - so try

echo $javascript->link('tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js');

and see if you get anywhere.

Comment: You should even skip the final .js: `echo $javascript->link('tiny_mce/tiny_mce');`

Comment: Yes, quite correct. It's also worth saying that if you ever get stuck then check out the code in the Bakery - it's full of real-world examples of syntax that you might not get from the documentation on your first read through: http://bakery.cakephp.org/categories/view/3